# How to close a ChromeDriver when running on Grid?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently running my tests with RemoteWebDriver with Selenium Grid 2 through TestNG suites. This works fine with Firefox and IE. Now I added Chrome and the tests run fine, but I always get an Exception when calling driver.quit() after all tests of a suite (works fine for FF and IE).

The Exception looks like this:

```
Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)    
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:346)
at setups.StandardChromeSetup.tearDown(StandardChromeSetup.java:42)
19 lines not shown

Caused by Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:467)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:346)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
at $Proxy1.quit(Unknown Source)
at  org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.quit(EventFiringWebDriver.java:194)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.DeleteSession.call(DeleteSession.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.DeleteSession.call(DeleteSession.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am using Selenium Version 2.24.1 and chromedriver.exe 21.0.1180.4

**EDIT**

Code for tearDown:

```
@AfterSuite
public void tearDown(){
  driver.quit();
}
```

Works perfectly for FF and IE with RemoteDriver and without. But not for chrome.

Comment: Can you post the code in setups.StandardChromeSetup.tearDown

Comment: added the info on tearDown it's nothing fancy

Comment: same setup & same problem here- I also get an os message that chromedriver.exe doesn't work anymore, when I confirm Google Chrome is killed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faced the same problem. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104341) is how I resolved it. This seems to be a bug with the new version of the Chrome driver. Using the previous version of the driver (20.0.1133.0) solved this issue for me.

Check the [driver download page](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

Comment: I am currently on vacation so I can't test it ;-) When I get back to work and it works I ll accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see the cause of this may be that you are not closing active browsers before quitting the `Driver`. Try to close the windows, which may be the cause of some exceptions, with the following code:

```
Driver.Close();
Driver.Quit();
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, but calling Close() before Quit() did not help.