# Selenium ChromeDriver stops working on Quit()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest, selenium-chromedriver

Using MSTest in Visual Studio, I am having a problem with Selenium WebDriver and, in particular, ChromeDriver. Whenever I call quit on the ChromeDriver, I get the message "chromedriver.exe" has stopped working" and the program freezes up.

I attempt to close each of my drivers at the end of all tests, in the class cleanup:

```
[ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup() {
            drivers.ForEach(x => x.Quit());
        }
```

The Firefox driver closes down fine but the Chrome driver always justs stops working. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: A bit more of my code, for clarity (the path points to the chromedriver.exe program that I have added into my solution):

```
static IWebDriver driver;
        static IWebDriver chromeDriver;
        static string baseURL;
        static List<IWebDriver> drivers;

[ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context) {
        drivers = new List<IWebDriver>();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(path);
        drivers.Add(driver);
        drivers.Add(chromeDriver);
        baseURL = "http://localhost:4444/";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187172/how-to-close-a-chromedriver-when-running-on-grid) solved my problem.

An earlier version of the driver [(20.0.1133.0)](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) quits and closes down without any problem, this fixed the problem for me.